# Count Number Of Messages Cleared By Bot

Tags: c#, discord.net

I have made this command for my discord bot that clears a certain number of messages in a channel. It currently does its job and does it well but when it shows the message at the end it shows the number of messages they wanted to clear. But lets say the channel only contains 20 messages but they do clear 50 i want it to show the number of messages it actually clears so instead of 50 it would show 20.

```
public class Clear : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    [Command("clear"),RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.ManageMessages)]
    public async Task ClearMessages(int numToClear)
    {
        EmbedBuilder builder = new EmbedBuilder();
        numToClear = numToClear + 1;

        var messages =  await Context.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(numToClear).Flatten();
        await Context.Channel.DeleteMessagesAsync(messages);

        builder.WithTitle("MESSAGES HAVE BEEN CLEARED!")
            .WithDescription($"A total of `{numToClear} messages` were cleared from this chat!")
            .WithColor(Color.DarkBlue);

        var clearedMessage =  await ReplyAsync("", false, builder.Build());
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        await clearedMessage.DeleteAsync();


    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like `var messages =  await Context.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(numToClear).Flatten();` the `messages` variable would hold the actual number of messages that are going to be cleared, just store the count.

Comment: sorry im quite new to c# could you explain further

Comment: After the `var messages = ...` and before `await Context.Channel.DeleteMessagesAsync(...)` put a `var actualCount = messages.Count;` which then contains the actual number of messages deleted.

Comment: i get the error "cannot assign method  group to an implicitly typed-variable - FIXED IT

Answer (score 0):

The `messages` variable has a `Count` property :

```
var count = messages.Count();
```

Or you can use the `numToClear` argument :

```
var count = numToClear;
```